# Replacing AngularJS date format with a blank

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS date format defined.

This works fine if a date is available. However, if the date is NULL, the following screen appears and was trying to figure out how to simply replace the date format with a blank.

[image]

### EDIT:

cODE bELOW:

**CS file:**

```
 namespace WarrantyUI.Models
    {
        public class CheckDepositViewModel
        {
            public string FunctionName { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyCheckDepositHeaderId { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyTotalAmount { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyJVNumber { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyCheckDepositSlipNumber { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyTransactionNumber { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyDateSubmittedToGL { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyDatePostedToGL { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyDateSubmittedToBank { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyCountryCode { get; set; }
            public bool readOnlyClaimStatusDescription { get; set; }
            public bool showCheckHeaderSearch { get; set; }
            public bool newCheckDeposit { get; set; }
            public bool ViewOnly { get; set; }
            public bool NewCheckDeposit { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

**CSHTML FILE**

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <label class="control-label align-left">DateSubmitted To GL:</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="gridCtrl.row.entity.DateSubmittedToGL" ng-readonly="'@Model.readOnlyDateSubmittedToGL'" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: can you show the code that generates this instead of a screenshot of the fields?

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.  This code wouldn't create that output;  something is missing here.

Answer (score 0):

I would do {{DateToBeshownScopeVariable || "" }} This will replace the filed with "" if the scope variable is null